# How to append key values to JSON file properly (without creating extra structure)?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I want to create JSON file in Python, which stores X and Y values. It should look for example like this:

```
{"X": [[1,2,3], [2,3,5], [1,2,6], [1,2,3], [2,3,5], [1,2,6]],"Y": [3,5,1,3,5,1]}
```

This is code I wrote, firstly I'm checking if the file is empty (if yes, then create X and Y in json file).

```py
  def save_data(x, y):
        data_from_json = {}
        with open('data_sets.json', 'r+') as json_file:
            if (os.stat('data_sets.json').st_size == 0):
                if "X" not in data_from_json:
                    data_from_json.setdefault('X', x)
                if "Y" not in data_from_json:
                    data_from_json.setdefault('Y', y)
                json.dump(data_from_json, json_file)
        with open('data_sets.json', 'r+') as json_file:
            data_from_json = json.load(json_file)
            data_from_json['X'].append(x)
            data_from_json['Y'].append(y)
            json.dump(data_from_json, json_file)
```

What I got is something like this:

```
{"X": [[1,2,3], [2,3,5], [1,2,6]],"Y": [3,5,1]}{"X": [[1,2,3], [2,3,5], [1,2,6]],"Y": [3,5,1]}
```

instead of appending X and Y with new values. What should I do?

Comment: The `if` tests in the first `with` block don't seem necessary. `data_from_json` is empty because you just created it, so the tests will obviously succeed. Did you mean to read from the file first?

Comment: And when you use `json.load()`, you're reading the same JSON that you just wrote. What's the point of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file is empty, you're writing the JSON to it twice. You write an initial dictionary, then you read the file again and append to the `X` and `Y` lists.

It's simpler to break the code path into two parts: one for creating an initial file, the other for appending to an existing file.

Also, if you use the same file opening to read and write the file, you need to call `seek()` between them to rewind to the beginning of the file. Otherwise you'll write the updated JSON after the original.

```
def save_data(x, y):
    if (os.stat('data_sets.json').st_size == 0):
        # File is empty, create initial dictionary
        data_from_json = {"X": [x], "Y", [y]}
        with open('data_sets.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(data_from_json, json_file)
    else:
        with open('data_sets.json', 'r+') as json_file:
            data_from_json = json.load(json_file)
            data_from_json.setdefault('X', [])
            data_from_json.setdefault('Y', [])
            data_from_json['X'].append(x)
            data_from_json['Y'].append(y)
            json_file.seek(0)
            json.dump(data_from_json, json_file)
```